# A source to learn database design

Tags: sql, database-design

I am looking to make a website and in the future desktop apps as well and i know nothing about db design so what tutorials or books (online preferably) are there? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [introduction to normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) in the MySQL manual is very good. There's also a list of resources at the end of the article.

Answer (score 0):

The T. Connolly 's [book](http://www.nhbs.com/database_systems_tefno_161037.html) is one of the best I've read so far.

> Database Systems : A Practical
>   Approach to Design, Implementation and
>   Management

Easy to pick up and cover a lot of topics.